# three.js rotate around line and toward camera

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to set rotation to box - it should rotate around the line (or to be more precise line should be the rotation axis) but it should be toward the camera. `If you still don't get the expected result - just imagine holding a lolly pop and rotate the stick in the way that the sweet part would look at the camera.`

I'm almost achieving the expected result but it is rotating around itself axis as well `- like in the example with lolly pop the sweet part is rotating around the point it is attached to the stick which is not the goal`

[image]

Here is the code sandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rotation-around-line-forked-smyqxx?file=/src/App.js

```
const FirstPoint = new THREE.Vector3(-0.02, 0.05, 0)
const SecondPoint = new THREE.Vector3(0.09, 0.01, -0.06)

    const box = meshRef.current

    box.position.copy(FirstPoint)

    var lineDirection = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(SecondPoint, FirstPoint).normalize()

    var cameraDirection = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(camera.position, FirstPoint).normalize()

    var rotationAxis = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(cameraDirection, lineDirection).normalize()

    box.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), rotationAxis)

    var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(lineDirection, Math.PI / 2)
    box.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(q, box.quaternion)
```